Redirecting using htaccess
I've looked at other suggestions and answers but I cannot seem to get it working.
Say I have a folder at localhost/CMS/public within that folder there is a index.php which it Directory Indexes to. Also in it there is a folder called pages. So for example,
localhost/CMS/public
-index.php
-pages/
 -login/
  -.htaccess
  -login.php

Is there a way I can go to localhost/CMS/public/ and it go to index.php while also when inputting localhost/CMS/public/login it'll show localhost/CMS/public/pages/login(which will get directory indexed to /login.php)?

Have a try disabling MultiViews in your virtual hosts configutation.
